# Share a channel with a Team with MS Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

do you know a way to share a channel with a Team from Graph?

I'm wondering if it's possible to do with Graph, what we can do with Teams right now...
[image]

The only endpoints that I found, seems that only allow to list or delete, but not to add.

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/92a86bffa6fdfe1ccbba8f44124c657108aa0428/concepts/whats-new-overview.md#teamwork-2

I don't find a method to share a channel or add there a Team...

Any idea would be appreciated.
Thanks